# Python App Engine will not deploy - timeout

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My app refuses to deploy, just writes

> Checking if deployment succeeded.
>
> Will check again in 60 seconds.

Over and over, then times out.

This is my .bat file:

> python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"
> --email=my email --passin update "app directory"

My internet connection works ok otherwise. Any ideas?

Full error:

```
2013-02-02 21:01:22,963 WARNING appcfg.py:2053 Version still not ready to serve,
 aborting.
2013-02-02 21:01:22,966 ERROR appcfg.py:2267 An unexpected error occurred. Abort
ing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2253, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2054, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
09:01 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in
<module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in
run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4377, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4368, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2605, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3115, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3097, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2253, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2054, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you're doing anything wrong. Sometimes Google App Engine is not responding the way you want, because they might have some issues on their side.

Try to change a version and redeploy (or use the `--version=version-name` in the command line). If that is not going to fix it, you'll have to wait a while and then try again